# UMP for $f(y)=\theta y^{\theta - 1}$ when $H_0: \theta = 1$

Tags: probability-theory, statistical-inference

The RV Y have PDF $$f(y)=\theta y^{\theta - 1}$$ for $0 \le y \le 1, \theta > 0$. Given only one obseravtion of Y, find the uniformly most powerful test with sign level $\alpha$ of $H_0: \theta = 1, H_1: \theta > 1$.

Shoudl I start by finding the distribution of Y given its PDF, or straight at it using the definitions?

---

Attempt: We know $L(\theta) = \prod f(y_i)$. Set $$L(\theta_0)/L(\theta_1)=k$$ then take logs, and solve for $y_i$ or $\sum y_i$. But I cannot do the algebra.

Comment: saying $\theta y^{\theta-1}> k' \iff y>k$

Comment: @Saty how does that help?

Comment: @Saty updated the question.

Comment: You said "Given only one obseravtion of Y" but in the update you're saying $y_i$!. I was thinking from Neyman-Pearson's Lemma/theorem.

Comment: Yes! Good. So I get $$\theta y^{\theta - 1} > k \Rightarrow ln(\theta) + (\theta-1)lny > lnk \Rightarrow y > exp[ (ln(k/\theta) \frac1{\theta-1} ]$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: $Y\sim Beta(\theta,1)$

**One observation case**: By NP-lemma Rejection region is the following
$$R=\{y:y>k_{\alpha}\}$$
But what is $k_{\alpha}$?. This is determined by the size of the test. i.e. epuating $P_{H_0}(R)=\alpha$. Or in other words  $P_{\theta=1}(Y>k_{\alpha})=\alpha$ where $Y\sim Beta(1,1)=U(0,1)$. So life is really a bed of roses in this case because  $P_{\theta=1}(Y>k_{\alpha})=1-k_{\alpha}$ and equating that to $\alpha$ we get $k_{\alpha}=1-\alpha$. Hence reject $H_0$ if $y>1-\alpha$.

The more interesting problem will be if we've more that 1 observations
i.e. $Y_i \overset{iid}{\sim} Beta(\theta,1)$. If you need any help regarding that let us know.